# How to set a 1:n relationship between Entity Data Models in combination with ASP.NET Core OData WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, odata

I receive Informations from a ASP.NET Core Web API with OData.

But if I try to get the Informations from my API (localhost:port/odata/groups) it only returns the ID and GroupName. The OutputFields are missing.

My Models are structured as follows:

```
public class OutputGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<OutputField> OutputField { get; set; }
}

public class OutputField
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    // Tryed to set a ForeignKey for the 1:n releationship
    public int GroupForeignKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupForeignKey")] 
    public OutputGroup OutputGroup { get; set; }
}
```

The EDM are created by this Method, where i tryed to define a reference between the EntitySets:

```
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        // create Builder Object                                                 
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        // OutputGroup-EntitySet
        builder.EntitySet<OutputGroup>("Groups")
               .HasManyBinding(g => g.OutputField, "Fields");
        // OutputField-EntitySet
        builder.EntitySet<OutputField>("Fields");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

with this code i´m defining the 1:n releationship between the Outputgroup and OutputField Entity:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<OutputGroup>()
                    .HasMany(g => g.OutputField)
                    .WithOne(f => f.OutputGroup)
                    .HasForeignKey("GroupForeignKey");
    }
```

My controller class returns the Groups as follows (there exists a second controller for the OutputFields build simular to this one):

```
    [ODataRoute("Groups")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_db.Groups); // The values are all correct in this variable
    }
```

I know i have to set the relationship between the entities, but i dont know why this isn´t working.

The Odata Metadata returns this [xml](https://ufile.io/dolat8ot).

My Project is based on this [tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/).

Comment: You are requesting a nested property add the $expand=OutputField to your OData request so that you let know EF that has to include that relationship

Comment: ok makes sense, have not used the expand function until now, because I thought my api behaves incorrectly. If I understood correctly, other Entity sets will not be included automatically and shouldn´t.